# Create this with grid system bootstrap

Tags: grid, system

```html
<section class="container">
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-md-8">
            <h4>Het Parool</h4>
            <h2>Help users choose the best online experience</h2>
        </div>
        <div class="col-md-4 float-md-right">
            <img class="preview" src="img/parool-half.png" />
        </div>
        <div class="col-md-6 float-md-left">
            <a class="btn btn-default" href="parool.html" role="button">Link</a>
        </div>
    </div>
</section>
```

I'm new to bootstrap and I am not totally getting the grid system.
I made a design here for desktop [Desktop version](https://i.stack.imgur.com/lbvPn.png)

And I want it to become this on mobile [Mobile version](https://i.stack.imgur.com/RdI9h.png)

Can someone explain to me how I can do this?

Thanks a lot!

Comment: What have you done so far (codeexample)?

Comment: So the html code above is what I got so far